# How to recursively copy files in MSBuild, *Where files to copy are specified on some file.txt*

Tags: msbuild

I read the list of files from a file. I want to copy and retain their folder structure - seen in the filename (the presence of a backslash or forwardslash), How do you do it? In short you don't have the metadata that you would get if you obtained the filename using wildcards. These options don't work for me http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msbuild/archive/2005/11/07/490068.aspx because I'm reading my filesToCopy from a file.

e.g files.txt contains

> folder//test1.txt
>   folder/subfolder/subsubfolder/test1.txt
>   folder/subfolder/test2.txt

So how can I copy these files without flattening all of them to one output file.

Answer (score 0):

You have one file per line.  I take it that is the source files, and the destination base directory is to be specified elsewhere?  I assume the `//` is not significant but illustrates that it may happen due to pasting paths together.

First, you can read in the data using [`ReadLinesFromFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164299%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).  You will populate an item list with one item per line.  So to get started,

```
<Target Name="mikezcopy">
    <ReadLinesFromFile File="files.txt">
        <Output TaskParameter="Lines" ItemName="FileItem" />
    </ReadLinesFromFile>
    ⋮
```

Now I'm guessing that these lines are relative to the source root and you give a dest root also, like with the command-line copy.  Source of each copy is one `FileItem` from the list, and destination is `$(dest)\%(FileItem.Identity)`.  That gives a command-line copy (or xcopy?) of

```
copy %(FileItem.Identity) $(dest)\%(FileItem.Identity)
```

which could be used with the `Exec` task, since the `Copy` task doesn't like the parameters you have available, but the cmd.exe copy intrinsic likes them just fine.

Notice that I used the syntax for a single element of the item list, so the task containing that will itself be batched.  I think you'd get the same results with:

```
    ⋮
    <Exec Command="copy &quot;@(FileItem)&quot; &quot;$(dest)\%(Identity)&quot;" />
```

That is, the presence of a list will cause the whole line to be iterated, and the attribute syntax refers to the same current iteration item.  I've not tried that line, so it might not be exactly right.  Use `Message` with the same string to see what you're getting.

Now, is the dest and source item relationship as I assumed?  If not quite, you need to articulate the arrangement more precisely, and then morph the string in a suitable way rather than simple concatenation `$(dest)\%(Identity)`.  String manipulation is possible using the .Net CLR System.String functions, and built-in `[MSBuild]::` property functions, and other classes from CLR where you can get the parameters to pass right.  If it's more complex than that, you can use an [inline task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd722601.aspx) and write a fragment in C# or VB.

Comment: Thanks, a lot. I would prefer to keep it within msbuild though :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ReadLinesFromFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164299%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) (as @ldlugosz correctly suggested), and then  use [MSBuild Copy task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3e54c37h.aspx) with [MSBuild Transformations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171476.aspx):

```
<Target Name="Build">
  <ReadLinesFromFile File="files.txt">
    <Output TaskParameter="Lines" ItemName="Files"/>
  </ReadLinesFromFile>

  <Copy SourceFiles="@(Files)" DestinationFiles="@(Files->'$(Outdir)%(relativedir)%(filename)%(extension)')" />
</Target>
```

Substituting `$(Outdir)` with whatever destination folder you want.

Comment: Worked, like a charm! :)